# boost interprocess condition blocking on notify_all

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, mutex, shared-memory

I have a managed shared memory segment which has a boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex and a boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition variable. I have 2 processes accessing the shared memory and they are synchronizing access based on the mutex and condition. I have come across a case where my first process blocks on notify_all method, initially I thought this was a non blocking method but it seems the interprocess condition implements a mutex which is used to synchronize itself.

The case where I get this deadlock is when process 2 is killed ungracefully while it is waiting on the condition, this I believe prevents the conditions mutex from being unlocked and then when I run process 2 again it blocks. Is there anyway to reset or clean up the interprocess condition the second time I start process 2.

Comment: May be related to https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21422

Answer (score 0):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp

Are you using *timed lock*?

For a simple dead-lock avoidance algorithm take a look here: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock_prevention_algorithms)
It's for threads but I believe it can be used with interprocess_locks.

> Recursively, only one thread is allowed to pass through a lock. 
>   If other threads enter the lock, they must wait until the initial thread
>   that passed through completes n number of times. But if the number of
>   threads that enter locking equal the number that are locked, assign
>   one thread as the super-thread, and only allow it to run (tracking the
>   number of times it enters/exits locking) until it completes.
>       After a super-thread is finished, the condition changes back to using the logic from the recursive lock, and the exiting super-thread
>
> - sets itself as not being a super-thread
> - notifies the locker that other locked, waiting threads need to re-check this condition
>
> If a deadlock scenario exists, set a new super-thread and follow that logic. Otherwise, resume regular locking.

Note that the above algorithm doesn't solve *livelock* situations, to prevent such behaviour use a `semaphore` if possible.

I was stunned to notice that interprocess_mutex doesn't support implement deadlock avoidance algorithms since these days, most mutex i.e `std::mutex` and `boost::mutex` already do.
I guess it's OS specific limitations.

> For more flexibility try using a [named_upgradable_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_upgradable_mutex.html)

Use a *timed lock* catch the exception when the process crashes and *remove* the *upgradable mutex*!. This type also allows *elevated* priviledges to be obtained by either thread!

Comment: I am using regular locks. It wont work in this case I think as when Process 2 crashes it is happens to be in wait on condition case so the synchronization mutex has been unlocked, but the number of waiters in the condition variable is set to 1 and the conditions local mutex is locked. When Process 1 runs and does a notify_all its see that the conditions mutex is still set and gets blocked on the notify_all. I need a way to clean up this condition when I happen to get a sudden crash of process 2, either by knowing it crashed and cleaning it up when I restart it or some other way.

Comment: @rudasi Check again :)

Comment: I cant use timed locks as I running time critical stuff, as soon as process 2 crashes I need to reset the state of the condition so process 1 does not block. Im thinking of using a windows mutex to check if process 2 has crashed.

Comment: Also I have had issues with boost named_mutex and named_conditions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731050/boost-named-condition-is-not-waking-up-waiting-process